# Silverlight crashes FireFox 3.5, IE7, & IE8

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, firefox-3

One of my users has an HP Pavilion DV4-1430us laptop running Windows Vista Professional 64-bit. She is using the latest version of the Silverlight Plug-In, downloaded on 24 July from microsoft.com/silverlight.

While typing in a text box in a silverlight web application my company developed, all three browsers will occasionally crash. Nine times out of ten, she can go back to the page where the crash occurred and pick up from where she left off, only to have it crash again several minutes later.

This only occurs while she is typing in a text box, and it only occurs on her laptop. I have watched her to confirm there is no user error.

Any thoughts?

Edit 1: I replicated the error. In Firefox 3.5, the window in which I was working closed with no warning, and the Mozilla Crash Reporter popped up. I'm pasting the crash report code:

> Add-ons: {20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b}:1.1,{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}:3.5.1
>
> BuildID: 20090715094852
>
> CrashTime: 1248713784
>
> InstallTime: 1248455260
>
> ProductName: Firefox
>
> SecondsSinceLastCrash: 245055
>
> StartupTime: 1248713511
>
> Theme: classic/1.0
>
> Throttleable: 1
>
> URL: [redacted]
> Vendor: Mozilla
>
> Version: 3.5.1

Edit 2: I replicated the error in IE8. I highlighted the text in a text box and began to type. Instantly,

> Internet Explorer has stopped working
>
> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.
> appeared.

Here is the event log entry:

`>Log Name:      Application`

`>Source:        Application Error`

`>Date:          7/27/2009 1:06:10 PM`
`>Event ID:      1000`

`>Task Category: (100)`

`>Level:         Error`

`>Keywords:      Classic`

`>User:          N/A`

`>Computer:      [computer name]`

`>Description:`

`>Faulting application iexplore.exe, version 8.0.6001.18702, time stamp 0x49b3ad2e, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 6.0.6000.16820, time stamp 0x4995210a, exception code 0xe0434352, fault offset 0x0001e05c, process id 0x1a54, application start time 0x01ca0edc4c7c0054.`

`>Event Xml:`

`><Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">`

`>  <System>`

`>    <Provider Name="Application Error" />`

`>    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>`

`>    <Level>2</Level>`

`>    <Task>100</Task>`

`>    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>`

`>    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2009-07-27T17:06:10.000Z" />`

`>    <EventRecordID>2636</EventRecordID>`

`>    <Channel>Application</Channel>`

`>    <Computer>[computer name]</Computer>`

`>    <Security />`

`>  </System>`

`>  <EventData>`

`>    <Data>iexplore.exe</Data>`

`>    <Data>8.0.6001.18702</Data>`

`>    <Data>49b3ad2e</Data>`

`>    <Data>kernel32.dll</Data>`

`>    <Data>6.0.6000.16820</Data>`

`>    <Data>4995210a</Data>`

`>    <Data>e0434352</Data>`

`>    <Data>0001e05c</Data>`

`>    <Data>1a54</Data>`

`>    <Data>01ca0edc4c7c0054</Data>`

`>  </EventData>`

`></Event>`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crash?

Comment: If you can, try debugging or remote debugging the silverlight app on this user's computer.

Comment: I am working to replicate the error now.

Comment: If you email me a .DMP file (ericlaw at microsoft) of IE when it crashes in this case, I'd be happy to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web app was written for Silverlight 2, and was trying to call System.ComponentModel.dll. The user was using the Silverlight 3 runtime, which does not include System.ComponentModel.

Solution: Downgrade user to Silverlight 2 until webapp can be rewritten for Silverlight 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling and re-enabling the Pen Tablet Service. It seems that Silverlight needs to access WispTis.exe or Wacomservice file for it to work properly. You can check to see if it is enabled by going to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services > Tablet PC Input Service. Make sure the service is started and set to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at FireFox's [bugzilla](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org) for issues in firefox.  You'll get a lot better idea of what todo.  If you look, you will see quite a number of simular faults.